# Upgrading Java on CentOS

Tags: centos, java, jdk

I'm currently working on a production server, and I can't get my Java program to be executed on it because of an incompatibility between the versions. Java 7 is installed on the server, while the program was compiled using Java 8.

I found out that the following package was installed : **jdk.x86_64**

I'm trying to use this [tutorial](http://lintut.com/how-to-install-java-8-on-rhel-centos-7-x-and-fedora-linux/), but it's mentioned that the **java-1.7.0-openjdk** package should be removed in order to install a new package.

I would like to know the difference between the packages (the one mentioned in the article and the one currently installed) and if it's safe to remove it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some applications are known to fail with the OpenJDK version, making them rely upon Oracle Java.  (Conversely, some application you want may rely upon OpenJDK—it's that kind of world).

In any upgrade of this type, you'll have to evaluate the result, to see if it improves things or breaks things.  There are a lot of opinions regarding either implementation.

Further reading:

- [Compatibility Guide for JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html)
- [Choosing between OpenJDK and Oracle JDK](http://www.coderanch.com/t/602572/java/java/Choosing-OpenJDK-Oracle-JDK)
- [Moving to OpenJDK as the official Java SE 7 Reference Implementation](https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/moving_to_openjdk_as_the)
- [Which Java package should I use: OpenJDK or Oracle JDK?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252607/which-java-package-should-i-use-openjdk-or-oracle-jdk)